# How to save a point as a variable in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

How I can define a point in tkz-euclide for later use? Obviously the below code does not work. I know I can save the x-y coordinates using something like `\def\x1{1} \def\y1{1} \def\x2{2} \def\y2{0}` then defining the point in each tikzpicture but I prefer then define the entire point and use it in all tikzpictues. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coordinate` to save the points. The coordinates can be used global afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```